# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set on Mac

Tags: java, macos, gdb, x11, x11-forwarding

I am running an application from terminal. It is expected to launch an Application specific debugger GUI which internally talks to GDB. I have tried {export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0} & {export DISPLAY=:0.0}. This doesn't work. 
On my linux machine I was able to run the application without the heck of setting DISPLAY.

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)`
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
at charm.debug.ParDebug.main(ParDebug.java:2291)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mac(s) don't run X11 by default (the core desktop environment on a Mac is also known as [Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_%28graphics_layer%29)). You'll need to install (and run) an X server. Per [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201341)

> X11 is no longer included with OS X, but X11 server and client libraries for OS X are available from the XQuartz project.

[XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) is available.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed XQuartz and then followed this tutorial, which also show the which configuration should be made on the Mac

http://dyhr.com/2009/09/05/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-with-ssh-on-mac-os-x-leopard/

Comment: The link is dead